# Bitlocker Recovery Key .txt file is empty

Tags: bitlocker

I have problem with **Bit-locker**...
**I have Recovery Key .txt files** (for 2 encrypted drives and created by Bitlocker) **but it is empty.**
How **can I** **unblock Bitlocker without Recovery Key**? Consider it that I have txt files with names (there is some codes or serial in names. I thought maybe it will be useful). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How can I unblock Bitlocker without Recovery Key?

This is not possible